# How to integrate the Google Places gem to obtain Google reviews

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-places

I have been following the "[google_places gem](https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-development/google-places-gem-21e9e1aac491)" tutorial and  am having trouble integrating the Google Places gem with my code to fetch Google reviews for my application.

I have obtained the permission and the API key has been enabled too, however, I have trouble accessing the request.

doctors_controller.rb:

```
class Manage::DoctorsController < Manage::BaseController
    # layout "design"
     require 'google-places'



  def show
    @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:id])
    authorize @doctor, :manage?
    @doctor = @location = @doctor.decorate
    #tring out google reviews
    api_key = "my_key"
    @client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(api_key) 
    @client = @client.spots(-33.8670522, 151.1957362, :types => 'restaurant')
  end
```

The error I get is:

```
GooglePlaces::RequestDeniedError in Manage::DoctorsController#show
This API project is not authorized to use this API.
```

How do I call them in `views.html`?

Comment: `api_key` would normally be defined in an environment variable. Where have you defined it in this code? It's not clear.

Comment: Why are you looking for reviews of your app on the places API? It would kind of make sense if you where looking for reviews of your business but an app is not a place.

Comment: Aside from the above comment, what API did you enable?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read all of "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". Your experience level isn't important, asking well-asked questions is.

Comment: I appreciate the support guys. So, my purpose here is to get google reviews of doctors in a given locality in my App. I have enabled geocoding API and google places API.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the environment variable. Think of an API KEY as the keys to your house. You don't want to let anyone you don't trust get their hands on those keys. Only you or the folks that live in your house — think of it as teams — would have the keys.

Now, the way you store the API key provided by Google is in an environment variable. An environment variable is just a secure way to store that API key and be able to fetch it from the application. You can read more about how Ruby uses environment variables [here](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/01/ruby-environment-variables/).

There is a [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem, that lets you create a `.env` file in which you can store your API keys.

.env:

```
GOOGLE_API_KEY=<<YOUR API KEY HERE>>
```

Now you can pass this API KEY to your script so that when the client makes a request to the Google API you get a response.

```
 @client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY'])
```

Also, your `show` method is too busy, which is an anti-pattern, but I think you can learn more about that later when you have a better understanding of Rails and Ruby.

Comment: thanks for the response, I have now put my credential in .env file for safer practice. would I have to pay to fetch google reviews in my app?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your API key is not valid because you got "no permission to this API". Maybe you  haven't enabled the Google Places API in your Google account.

1. Make sure that your `api_key` is still valid. "[Get an API Key](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key)" explains how.
2. If it works you should hide your sensitive `api_key`   in Rails' [credentials](https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336) (>= Rails 5.2) and then use it in your controller.

   ```
   @client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(Rails.application.credentials[:api_key])
   ```

Comment: The API key **is** valid. If it was not, the error would be different.

Comment: Yes, but still from some reasons he don't have access to this API. As I wrote probably Places API is not turned on. :)

Comment: Yes, I did it because you didn't catch the context. I posted a link to Places API early and you didn't check it.

Comment: I had enabled Goecoding API by mistake, now I have enabled Google places.However, I am getting this message now. You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started. I thought this service was free to implement, is it not?

Comment: It was free but from [July 16th 2018 Google implemented a pricing plan](https://www.shoredigitalinc.com/google-maps-is-no-longer-free/). Here is explantation and billing [details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing).

Comment: yes, that explains. However, I opted for a free billing account one month trial. unfortunately, I am still facing the same issue.